# Find controls values inside any container

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my ASP.NET page, I have an Accordion containing Panes. 
Panes contains themselves differents controls like textbox, label, dropdownlist, checkbox, personnal web control...

I need to check (client side) if textboxes, dropdownlists, textboxes & dropdownlist inside my personnal webcontrol, are empty or not.

I need a loop to check every Container.

Can you help me ?

Comment: just use `$('input,select,textarea')` or `$(':input')`

Comment: `var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text], select");` will give all `input type="text"` and `select` elements